# select where param = ? but if ? is a blank space, return any value for that column

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, request, prepared-statement

Receiving some strings, ints and dates from my request, like:

```
String city = request.getParameter("city");
```

Those values are the ones written by the user in my web. The problem is, if my user wants to not fill an input, for example, city, the query should consider that city can be any value. As I'm gonna get a blank space in my `request.getParameter` (if user doesnt fill the input text), I tried to tell the query that if a parameter is a blank space, it must return any value. I tried:

```
String getResults = "SELECT id_housing, name, description_short, price, photo FROM housing 
WHERE (city = ? OR ? = '')AND init_date <= ? AND end_date >= ? AND (price = ? OR ? = '') AND (guests = ? OR ? = '')"; 

PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(getResults);
stmt.setString(1, city);
stmt.setString(2, city);
stmt.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(initDate.getTime()));
* and so on... *
```

The query runs, but it's not returning any housings. How can I specify that a **?** can be any value if it is bonded to a parameter that is a blank space?

PD: I would prefer not to build a dynamic WHERE clause, adding or removing things from the query.

Comment: It helps clarify if you describe the problem better than "It's not working". Is the query running and returning unexpected results, or are you getting an error, etc....?

Comment: @csalmhof read my PD, I said that I would prefer not to add or remove from the where clause, and Im not saying the parameter is null, Im saying is a blank space

Comment: @Uueerdo sorry, I meant the query runs but it doesnt return anything

Comment: it looks to me like you are handling it correctly appropriately; perhaps include at least the remaining five `stmt.set` statements in the question in case you inadvertently omitted the real source of the problem; you should also the execution call as well. Also, you've made sure the same query returns results from something like MySql Workbench, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are trying to pass a column name as an argument, but this does not work.  
You are allowed to pass values only for the columns.  
I propose another solution for your problem. 
Consider this simpler statement:

```
String getResults = "SELECT id_housing, name, description_short, price, photo FROM housing 
WHERE (city = ? OR 1 = ?)
```

**(1)** If the user has entered a **valid** value then your code will be:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(getResults);
stmt.setString(1, city_text);
stmt.setString(2, 0);
```

so the `WHERE` clause looks like:

```
WHERE (city = city_text OR 1 = 0)
```

since `1 = 0` is always `false`, the remaining part `city = city_text` will fetch the desired rows.

**(2)** If the user has **not** entered a value then your code will be:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(getResults);
stmt.setString(1, "");
stmt.setString(2, 1);
```

so the `WHERE` clause looks like:

```
WHERE (city = '' OR 1 = 1)
```

since `1 = 1` is always `true`, the whole Boolean statement `(city = '' OR 1 = 1)` will be `true` so it is as it does not even exist.

So you have to check the value entered or not entered and adjust the parameters to pass in any case.  
This is just an idea which you can extend for more columns.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose if parameter is blank then you will get a list of results. If you are prepared for it then add parameter to the query with a condition when not empty or empty. Pulling data on empty is improper. Consider designing in other way. If there are many empty results , you can't keep index on empty value. Then it will trigger performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your where-clause, `(city = ? OR ? = '')` should be `(city = ? OR city = '')`.

So:

```
SELECT id_housing, name, description_short, price, photo FROM housing 
WHERE (city = ? OR city = '') 
    AND init_date <= ? AND end_date >= ? 
    AND (price = ? OR price = '') 
    AND (guests = ? OR guests = '')
```

This would be equivalent:

```
SELECT id_housing, name, description_short, price, photo FROM housing 
WHERE city in ('', ?)
    AND init_date <= ? AND end_date >= ? 
    AND price in ('', ?)
    AND guests in ('', ?)
```

Obviously, you will have to adjust the code that sets the parameter values appropriately.